# How to capture Control+D signal?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I want to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> signal in my program and write a signal handler for it.
How can I do that?
I am working on *C* and using a *Linux* system.

Comment: you could start by specifying the platform and language!

Answer (score 95):

As others have already said, to handle <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, handle "end of file"s.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is a piece of communication between the user and the pseudo-file that you see as stdin. It does not mean specifically "end of file", but more generally "flush the input I typed so far". Flushing means that any `read()` call on stdin in your program returns with the length of the input typed since the last flush. If the line is nonempty, the input becomes available to your program although the user did not type "return" yet. If the line is empty, then `read()` returns with zero, and that is interpreted as "end of file".

So when using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to end a program, it only works at the beginning of a line, or if you do it twice (first time to flush, second time for `read()` to return zero).

Try it:

```
$ cat
foo
   (type Control-D once)
foofoo (read has returned "foo")
   (type Control-D again)
$
```

Comment: Hey, for anyone else who finds this question; please stop up voting this solution. It may be 'technically correct' in that control-D is not a signal, but for programmers, it's the most useless answer on this whole page.

Comment: @Doug Most programmers who want to handle control-D simply want to handle EOF. I don't see any indication in the question that the OP wants to be able to read control-D as an input character. The answer could be more complete by including a specific way to handle control-D, but the OP did not provide any code, so it is hard to make any modification suggestion other than looking at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+eof . Perhaps your answer would be a better fit for a question that specifically asks how to treat control-D as an ordinary input character.

Comment: The issue here is that this answer doesn't answer the question. 'Just handle EOF'. HOW? How do you keep your application from being terminated and read from stdin? Do you reopen stdin somehow? 'Just do this thing, which actually I'm not going to tell you how to do' is an extremely unhelpful answer.

Comment: @Doug This second comment makes it clearer what you mean than your first comment, which is more of a patronizing call to evaluate the answer the same way you evaluate it with no justification provided.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis For me it is still working exactly the way it was when I wrote this answer: First Ctrl-D causes “foofoo” to be shown, and second Ctrl-D takes me back to the terminal. I have never encountered a terminal that worked differently (on OS X and Linux), but perhaps your terminal is withholding the first Ctrl-D for some reason?

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I frequently forget that I have `alias cat='bat -pp'` in my `.bashrc`. False alarm. `command cat` works as expected.

Answer (score 41):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is **not** a *signal*, it's EOF (End-Of-File). It closes the stdin pipe. If read(STDIN) returns 0, it means stdin closed, which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> was hit (assuming there is a keyboard at the other end of the pipe).

Comment: Talking of _pipe_ here is misleading. `CTRL-D` is only relevant for terminal devices, not pipes, and it's only relevant on the master side of the pseudo-terminal or when sent by the (real) terminal, and only when in `icanon` mode.

Comment: This answer is misleading, I don't get how it has been upvoted this much.

Comment: "It closes the stdin pipe". What, no. It just sets the eof flag, which can be then reset with `clearerr`.

Answer (score 17):

A minimalistic example:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <termios.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

void sig_hnd(int sig){ (void)sig; printf("(VINTR)"); }

int main(){
  setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

  struct termios old_termios, new_termios;
  tcgetattr(0,&old_termios);

  signal( SIGINT, sig_hnd );

  new_termios             = old_termios;
  new_termios.c_cc[VEOF]  = 3; // ^C
  new_termios.c_cc[VINTR] = 4; // ^D
  tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&new_termios);

  char line[256]; int len;
  do{
    len=read(0,line,256); line[len]='\0';
    if( len <0 ) printf("(len: %i)",len);
    if( len==0 ) printf("(VEOF)");
    if( len >0 ){
      if( line[len-1] == 10 ) printf("(line:'%.*s')\n",len-1,line);
      if( line[len-1] != 10 ) printf("(partial line:'%s')",line);
    }
  }while( line[0] != 'q' );

  tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&old_termios);
}
```

The program change the VEOF char (from Ctrl-D) to Ctrl-C and the VINTR char (from Ctrl-C) to Ctrl-D. If You press Ctrl-D then the terminal driver will send a SIGINT to the signal handler of the program.

Note: pressing VINTR will erase the terminal input buffer so You can not read the characters typed in the line before the VINTR key pressed.

Comment: Your `main` paramter list needs a `void`. This is not C++.

Comment: Technically, this _is_ C++. `g++ -std=c++03 test.cpp` compiles and runs just fine :)

Comment: Just to get cute with you: But the OP asked about C... :)

Comment: What does the TCSANOW do in your tcsetattr?

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to process signals.

You need to ensure ISIG is not set on the terminal flags, that's all.

Here's a complete contained example using select to avoid blocking on stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define STDIN_FILENO 0

struct termios org_opts;

/** Select to check if stdin has pending input */
int pending_input(void) {
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set fds;
  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;
  FD_ZERO(&fds);
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds); //STDIN_FILENO is 0
  select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  return FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
}

/** Input terminal mode; save old, setup new */
void setup_terminal(void) {
  struct termios new_opts;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &org_opts);
  memcpy(&new_opts, &org_opts, sizeof(new_opts));
  new_opts.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ECHOPRT | ECHOKE | ISIG | ICRNL);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_opts);
}

/** Shutdown terminal mode */
void reset_terminal(void) {
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &org_opts);
}

/** Return next input or -1 if none */
int next_input(void) {
  if (!pending_input())
    return -1;
  int rtn = fgetc(stdin);
  printf("Found: %d\n", rtn);
  return(rtn);
}

int main()
{
  setup_terminal();

  printf("Press Q to quit...\n");
  for (;;) {
    int key = next_input();
    if (key != -1) {
      if ((key == 113) || (key == 81)) {
        printf("\nNormal exit\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  reset_terminal();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
doug-2:rust-sys-sterm doug$ cc junk.c
doug-2:rust-sys-sterm doug$ ./a.out
Press Q to quit...
Found: 4
Found: 3
Found: 27
Found: 26
Found: 113

Normal exit
```

NB. 3 is control C and 4 is control D; 26 is control z. 113 is 'q'.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters for a full table.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is translated  by the system to end of standard input so your app won't get any signal.

I think that the only way to intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is to work directly with the system api (like accessing tty)

Answer (score 1):

You can use poll() and watch for POLLHUP on fd #1, because the TTY layer translates ^D to EOF.

Comment: VEOF (^D) does not transformed to be an EOF. If You press VEOF the program will receive a partial buffer as Pascal Cuoq wrote.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> value in ascci table is 4 and is a non printable characters. 
So your can capture it in a terminal with the following code.
When getline function get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> an error occur and return value is -1.
Your can make a condition on the return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
    size_t size = 500;
    int nb = getline(&buf, &size, stdin);
    if (nb == -1)
        printf("CTRL + D captured\n");
    free(buf);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if stdin is not of with the `feof` method like so:

```cpp
if (feof(stdin))
{
    // some code
    exit(0);
}
```

See [this](https://github.com/2KAbhishek/cshell/blob/d8759cba54815f770b2900a4648adba551f08801/src/cshell.c#L500) for more details/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, `getline()` will return -1 on failure to read a line (including the end-of-file condition). In event of an error, `errno` is set to indicate the cause.

This means:

- When `getline()` encounters a failure it will return -1 and set `errno` global variable with the value of the error code
- When `getline()` reads `CTRL+D` it will return -1 but won't set `errno` global variable.

`EINVAL` and `ENOMEM` are the two possible error values that can be set for `errno` by `getline()`.

So you can construct your code in such a way as to test if the -1 value returned by `getline()` was a result of an end-of-file condition or an error like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void)
{
     char *buffer = NULL;
     size_t bufsize = 0;
     ssize_t characters;
     /* initialize errno to 0 (this value will be changed if getline() 
      * encounters an error 
      */
     errno = 0;

     characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
     if (characters == -1 && errno == 0)
     {
           printf("You entered CTRL+D\n");
     }
     free(buffer);
     return (0);
}
```