# Communication with process using pipes in Python

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I have a process with which I can communicate on the command line like this:

```
% process -
input
^D^D
output
```

So: I start the process, type some input and after hitting Ctrl-D twice, I get the output. 
I want to make a Python wrapper around this process. I created this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('process -', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
        input = raw_input('Enter input: ')
        p.stdin.write(input)
        p.stdin.close()
        p.wait()
        output = p.stdout.read()
        print output
```

This works the first time, but after that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    p.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Is there another way to interact with this process without closing the file?

Comment: The problem is a bit more complicated. As I see it now you have to remove those closing lines, add `p.stdin.flush()` and catch the SIGINT signal. And when it occures you have to pass it to the subprocess and **then** `p.wait()` (or better `p.communicate()`), print the output and close the process.

Answer (score 0):

[`p.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) will wait until the subprocess has exited prior to returning, so on the second iteration in your script, `p` has exited already (and has therefore closed `p.stdin`).

Answer (score 0):

If the proccess you're wrapping ends after the first ouput, the comunication will fail to the second. Due all pipes (stdin and stdout) will be closed. Hence the error:

`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

Each time you try to send input to the wrapped process, this must be expecting that input and pipes must be opened.

On the other hand is what Thomas said in his answer, `p.wait()` is not the way to go for repetitive input/output strategy.

You can't use [subprocess.Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) neither, due it calls [subprocess.Popen.wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) internally.

You can try use `p.stdin.write` and `p.stdout.read` here you have a good article about the subject: [Writing to a python subprocess pipe](https://gist.github.com/waylan/2353749)

Answer (score 0):

To emulate the shell session:

```
$ process -
input
^D^D
output
```

In Python, using [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(['process', '-'], input='input\n', universal_newlines=True)
print(out, end='')
```

---

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is recognized as EOF (terminate the input) by a Unix terminal (`$ stty -a` -- look for `eof = ^D` and `icanon` in the output). If you need to type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice ([at the beginning of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261742/4279)); it might indicate a bug in the `process` program such as ["`for line in sys.stdin:` doesn't notice `EOF` the first time" Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1633941).