# Why does Python3.2 require 3 ctrl+D to exit, but Python3.3 only 2?

Tags: python, stdin, eof, tty

Run the following script:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

Then type:

```
a<ctrl-d><ctrl-d><ctrl-d>
```

In Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, the program will terminate after just 2 `<ctrl-d>`, but in Python 3.1 and 3.2, it takes 3.

Any clues as to why this is?

Comment: It shouldn't even take 2. See [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1633941). The short answer is: because bugs, and those were fixed.

Comment: Python 3 got a new I/O subsystem, and most bugs were ironed out by 3.3. So in 3.0-3.2 there may have been issues. I'm not going to dig up exactly which bug was fixed for this specific behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters one ^D (End of File) is normally enough, but with a pending input, the first ^D ends the input stream (and in IDLE Shell results in printing of 0 for 0 chars written) and the second kills the program.  In Windows console, ^Z\n is required instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why shouldn't it take 2?  According to POSIX, the first EOF flushes the pending input, the second EOF (with no pending input) causes read() to return 0  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21261742/4956890

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: right, I missed the the pending input there.