# Making sure the input is a charachter

Tags: c, input

This might be a rookie question, but I need to make sure that the input given by the user is of data type char [%c] or a string [%s].

If it were an integer, I would just do something like this:

```
    int data, x;
    do {
      printf("Please enter a number: ");
      x = scanf(" %d", &data);
      getchar();
    } while(x!=1);
```

So I was wondering if there's a similar way to do this, if the input is supposed to be a string or a character. Thanks, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Its better to check with [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value

Comment: Provide some sample inputs, to receive better answers

Comment: Unless your hit EOF or some actual stream error, character and/or string input will *always* succeed. It can literally  be *anything*, so unless you're going to specify considerably stricter semantics and precise protocol for what you mean, there is no realistic answer to your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig  It's for an assignment and i have to somehow make sure the user types in an alphabet. I've done this with an integer before, but i have no idea where to start from when it comes to char or a string.

Comment: @IrAM I would provide some sample inputs, but I'm still trying to figure out where to start from..

Comment: So... the restriction isn't just "string" or "character", it's *alphabetic* ? That's what I'm talking about: precise requirements. So, non-alphabetic characters (punctuation, control characters, whitespace, etc) are off the menu. Just a..z and A..Z. ? What about 0..9 ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, exactly. The input has to be the alphabets from A to Z and the lower case letters should work as well. 0.. 9 shouldn't! Apologies for not making it clear earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to use `%c` in `scanf()` because some unexpected character like `\r\n` will be input.

You can use a `char[2]` to receive a single character. An `\0` will be filled after your string to represent the end of string, so the length of array must be bigger than 1.

An example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char data[2];

    scanf("%1s", data);

    if (data[0] >= 'a' && data[0] <= 'z') // custom your constraint here
    {
        // legal
        printf("legal: %s", data);
    }
    else
    {
        // illegal
        printf("illegal: %s", data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While I input `b`, the `data` will be `"b\0"`.

Comment: Consider a width limit `scanf("%1s", data);` so code behaves well enough  even when input is more than 1.

Comment: Do not use `data[0] >= 'a' && data[0] <= 'z'` to test for letters. It is not guaranteed to work by the C standard. Use `isalpha` to test for a letter and, if desired, `islower` to test for lowercase. They are declared in `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

part of the answer is if you just want to read only alphabet you can use below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do {
        printf("enter a char:");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
    }while(!isalpha(ch));
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update 1:**

Just for the completeness and for the **FUN** part of the programing, have added code here.

This works well *(not tested robustly, you can do if you need to)* for the single `char` input or for a string of length 9.

Remember to type the `EOF` after input is entered in case length of input is  < 9.

and read [EOF behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260674/why-do-i-need-to-type-ctrl-d-twice-to-mark-end-of-file) on same line and new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LEN 10

int main()
{
    char ch;
    char str[LEN] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int ret;
    printf("enter a char or string(len = 9) and press EOF if len < 9\n");
    do {
        if(1== (ret = scanf(" %c",&ch)))
        {
            if(isalpha(ch))
                str[i++] = ch;
        }                
        else
            printf("scanf:Error (%d)\n", ret);
    }while(ret != EOF && ( !isalpha(ch) || i < LEN-1));
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("str is %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The naked `scanf` (i.e. never checking the result to ensure you actually read a character) will irritate more than its fair share of engineers, even if the odd professor doesn't know/care any better. Regardless, this is at least a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank You! As far as I know isalpha() wouldn't work with a string though, would it?

Comment: @dean_winchester added code to read the strings, it is just for FUN, you can use it if you need the same behavior.