# I'm trying to give numbers thru console and trying to print them. The loop is executing continuously. Not getting the desired result

Tags: loops, perl, while-loop, printing

Randomly giving the numbers as input. Loop is not exiting even after pressing ctrl+d

```
my $num;
my @numbers =();

print("\n enter the numbers :\n");
print("\n press ctrl+d to exit once done\n");

while (my $input = <>) {
    print(">");
    #chomp $input;
    $num =int($input);
    push(@numbers, $num);
}
print( " entered number are :@numbers\t");
```

Comment: Are you hitting enter first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to type Ctrl-D twice to mark end-of-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260674/why-do-i-need-to-type-ctrl-d-twice-to-mark-end-of-file)

Comment: Hi Shawn. Even I'm hitting enter, there's no response

Comment: In my case CTRL+D isn't working

Comment: works for me (Linux, Bash). But my guess is that the output isn't flushed correctly so that the output doesn't appear when you expect it to appear. The program also has some minor cosmetic bugs (e.g. no `>` before the first time input is expected)

Comment: Works for me on Windows, although in cmd prompt it is Ctrl-Z instead of Ctrl-D. Add more info about your problem, or the question will and should be closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: Instead of forcing the user to enter an EOF command, you could just end the loop at a given input, or lack thereof. I.e. `last if $input !~ /\d/`, or `last if $input =~ /q/i` (Q for quit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To signal EOF on Windows, use Ctrl-Z followed by Enter. (You'll need to use it on a blank line when using `<>`.)

To signal EOF on unix, use Ctrl-D<sup>[1]</sup> immediately after having pressed Enter.

If these don't work, it's an issue with your terminal.

---

1. Ctrl-D is only the default. `stty -a` will show the current setting.

   ```
   $ stty -a
   ...; eof = ^D; ...
   ```

Comment: I have tried giving input numbers and have CTRL+Z being pressed followed by enter key. I could see the following error.   " ^Z
Argument "^Z\n" isn't numeric in int at new.pl line 406, <> line 5. "

Comment: 1
2
3
4
5^Z
Argument "^Z\n" isn't numeric in int at new.pl line 406, <> line 5.

Comment: I don't know what you're terminal you're using. In any case, this has nothing to do with Perl. This is about knowing how to use your own terminal.

Comment: I am using notepad++ with perl being  used as a plugin. And I'm checking the result then and there in NPP.