# Getting input in the if condition

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy input to output
// my version

int main()
{
    int c;

    printf("\n\nUse CONTROL + D to terminate this program\n\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }

    if ((c = getchar()) == EOF) {
        printf("\n\nProgram TERMINATED\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, the body of the `if` statement runs. That's what I had wanted, but as I analyzed the code more thoroughly, shouldn't it ask for my input again since the `if`'s condition is `(c = getchar()) == EOF`?

Comment: Why `int` instead of `char` ?

Comment: @alex: Because `getchar` returns an `int` (actually an `unsigned char` casted to `int`, or `EOF` - which by definition is a negative number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit `^D`, input to the program is closed, so `getchar()` will subsequently always return `EOF`.

Comment: Then how do I get input again if every call to `getchar()` wouldn't work after `^D`?

Comment: Use something other than `^D` (and the subsequent end-of-file) to terminate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Control-D is canonical mode end-of-file character.  When entered *at the beginning* of a line it causes an EOF condition to be seen by the process, that is the read returns 0.  However if if Control-D is entered somewhere other than the beginning of the line it just causes the read to return immediately with what has been input thus far.

If you hit Control-D twice in a row you should see what I think you asking about.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516122/how-to-capture-controld-signal/1516177#1516177) is a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

^D terminates the program instantly. Thus you're getchar would never return when ^D is hit.

That is why REPL like python exits using 'exit()'.

If you want, try to use 'q' for quiting:

Comment: This could be phrased better - `^D` doesn't in general terminate programs, just their input. The program could feel free to ignore the lack of input and go on its merry way.