# How to handle signal for ctrl+n and ctrl+d?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

SIGINT is used to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> but there is no signal for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, how can I handle these? Any idea?

I have a link list in my program and I have to perform some link list operations in these signal handlers. I just want to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> in the normal flow of program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1516414/390913

Comment: CTRL-D is EOF (e.g. when reading from stdin, so typically does not cause a signal). What do you expect CTRL+n to do ? Could you tell us about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: You may be looking for [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture Control+D signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516122/how-to-capture-controld-signal)