# ctrl-d didn't stop the while(getchar()!=EOF) loop

Tags: c, unix, eof

Here is my code. I run it in ubuntu with terminal. when I type (a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) in terminal, the program didn't stop but continued to wait for my input.

Isn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> equal to EOF in unix?

Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    int d;
    while(d=getchar()!=EOF) {
        printf("\"getchar()!=EOF\" result is %d\n", d);
        printf("EOF:%d\n", EOF);
    }
        printf("\"getchar()!=EOF\" result is %d\n", d);
}
```

Comment: That's not recursion. It's just an infinite loop until you EOL the input. Recursion = function calling itself directly or after some other intermediate number of steps.

Comment: Compiled that with gcc, hitting `^D` stopped the loop for me.

Comment: @JonLin Simply input ^D .It works for me,too. However, when the input is (a^D);the loop didn't stop.

Comment: @MarcB I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EOF is not a character. The `EOF` is a macro that `getchar()` returns when it reaches the end of input or encounters some kind of error. The `^D` is not "an EOF character". What's happening under linux when you hit ^D on a line by itself is that it closes the stream, and the `getchar()` call reaches the end of input and returns the `EOF` macro. If you type `^D` somewhere in the middle of a line, the stream isn't closed, so `getchar()` returns values that it read and your loop doesn't exit.

See the [**stdio** section of the C faq](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/index.html) for a better description.

Additionally:

> On modern systems, it does not reflect any actual end-of-file character stored in a file; it is a signal that no more characters are available.

Comment: I carefully read the website. In my opinion, if I type `^D` somewhere in the middle of a line, bash will tackle `^D`. As a result, the C program didn't get a command to close the stream. If I type `^D` in a single line, the C program will get the correct command. Am I right?

Comment: @qingfeng There's a bit more about `^D` here: http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/eofval.html But yeah, the stream won't get closed unless it's on a line by itself. Short explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/851273

Comment: When the terminal is in canonical mode, lines aren't transmitted over the tty device until you press enter. Pressing the configured EOF key (^D by default) causes the data to be immediately transmitted and any `read` waiting on it to return with the number of characters available. If the line already has data on it, this will be a normal, non-zero-length read. If the line is empty, this will result in a zero-length read, which is the *definition* of end-of-file status on a file descriptor. Thus the stdio layer will interpret it as EOF status.

Comment: @qingfeng: bash has nothing to do with it; the input is being handled by the program that's currently running.

Comment: @R.., Your comment should be an answer, and it should be the top answer. It's getting hard to find the full "behind-the-scenes" information these days...

Comment: Note that the stream does not get closed when you indicate EOF; it goes into the error state, but that can be cleared with `clearerr()`, and you can try again.  If the input device is a terminal, you may get new input.  If you opened the file, you still need to close it (though exiting the program will also close it).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Jon Lin's answer about EOF, I am not sure the code you wrote is what you intended. If you want to see the value returned from `getchar` in the variable `d`, you need to change your `while` statement to:

```
    while((d=getchar())!=EOF) {
```

This is because the inequality operator has higher precedence than assignment. So, in your code, `d` would always be either `0` or `1`.

Comment: It's very kind of you to be so meticulous. But I just want to verify that the expression `d=getchar()!=EOF` is 0 or 1.

Comment: @Sam: You can make it clear that you are assigning the result of the comparison by writing: `while ((d = (getchar() != EOF)) != 0)` or as `while ((d = (getchar() != EOF)))` so that the compiler won't throw warnings at you.  The more common alternative is `while ((d = getchar()) != EOF)` which assigns the result of `getchar()` to `d` and then compares it with EOF.  That to avoids compiler warnings.  Many modern compilers will generate a warning for what you wrote.