# Useful context of scanf(...) != EOF

Tags: c, scanf

Soo... I saw a guy claim this code was working on another question.

```
while(scanf("%X", &hex) != EOF) {
    //perform a task with the hex value. 
}
```

So, in what context does the EOF flag get thrown?  I though it would just keep asking for a number indefinitely.  I added another line of code to test it, and it does exactly what I expected it too.....

This isn't a file, this seems to be stdin.  So.... WHEN is this code useful?
*Ie, in what context is the EOF return thrown?*

Comment: I think if you press ctrl-D you may get the EOF...

Comment: See [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944314/ctrl-d-didnt-stop-the-whilegetchar-eof-loop)

Comment: `EOF` isn't a flag that's thrown. It's a macro that expands to a constant expression of type `int`, typically `(-1)`. `scanf` returns the value of `EOF` when it's defined to do so by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for `scanf`, you will read that the value `EOF` is returned if a read failure occurred before the first value was assigned.  (*ie* end of file)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

You could equally test:

```
while(scanf("%X", &hex) == 1)
```

This is my preference.  I expect one input, so I will be explicit.

Comment: And what sir... would be likely to cause such a read failure?

Comment: That particular failure would occur if the input stream is closed (`EOF`).  If the input is simply invalid (*ie* not a hexadecimal character), it will return `0` instead.

Comment: What this means is that if you loop while not `EOF` and you receive bad input, as it currently stands you won't realise it and you will keep looping indefinitely.  Consider storing the result of the function call in a variable or using my more explicit loop condition.

Comment: Thanks... between us, I think we've put together a whole answer!

Answer (score 0):

Realistically speaking, this input is good on linux because ^d will end the stream, thus throwing the 'error.'

On windows, this behavior is different... whatever it is is not ctrl+d.  At least I know now though, since I use both.

Thanks!

Comment: On DOS (and early Windows, haven't checked in a _long_ time) end-of-file was signalled with ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF`  is returned on I/O error and end-of-file.  With `stdin`, an I/O error is a rare event and with keyboard input the end-of-file indication usual takes a special key sequence.

A practical use occurs with redirected input.

Assume a program exists that reads hexadecimal text and prints out decimal text:

```
// hex2dec.c
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void) {
  unsigned hex;
  int cnt;
  while((cnt = scanf("%X", &hex)) == 1) {
    printf("%u\n", hex);
  }
  // At this point, `cnt` should be 0 or EOF
  if (cnt != EOF) {
    puts("Invalid hexadecimal sequence found.");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

// hex.txt contents:
abc
123
```

Conversion occurs with the command

```
hex2dec < hex.txt
2748
291
```

By detecting `EOF` on the `stdin`, the program knows when to return.