# How to count words in a document assuming the text file has multiple spaces

Tags: c

The goal is basically to recreate `wc`. I need to count words, characters, non white space characters and new lines. I have everything except words I can't figure out how to make it work.

When I searched here everyone was under the assumption that the document did not have multiple white spaces between words. The documents I have to test with are guaranteed to have multiple spaces so this method for counting words does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int Spaces;
  Spaces = 0;
  int NewLine;
  NewLine = 0;
  int Characters;
  Characters = -1;
  char* filename = argv[1];

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: \n   wc <filename>\n");
  } else {
    printf("Filename is: %s\n", filename );
    FILE* infile;
    infile = fopen(filename, "r");

    char c;
    do {
      if (c == ' ') {
        Spaces = Spaces + 1;
      }
      if (c == '\n') {
        NewLine = NewLine + 1;
      }
      Characters = Characters + 1;
    } while ((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF);

    printf("Total number of characters: %d\n", Characters);
    Characters = Characters - NewLine - Spaces;
    printf("Total number of non-whitespace characters: %d\n", Characters);
    printf("Total number of lines: %d\n", NewLine);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem you're asking about, but you should change your `do`/`while` loop to a plain `while` loop and change `c` to an `int`.

Comment: `c` is uninitialized. (and more)

Comment: Note: `char c;` --> `int c;` to distinguish `EOF` from all other `char`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489630/why-eofend-of-file-isnt-working-at-the-end-of-a-line-without-a-n-before-it) is a question I asked on another topic, but the code there may prove to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use a Boolean variable, typically named something like `in_word`, which you set to `false` if the current character is white-space, and `true` if it's not. You increment the word count when (and only when) it changes from `true` to `false` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Implement your code as having two states: in-a-word and not-in-a-word. Then increment your count when transitioning between states.

I suggest incrementing word count when transitioning from not-in-a-word to in-a-word (as opposed to in-a-word to not-in-a-word), so no special processing will be needed at the end of the file.