# Bash: What C-d really does?

Tags: bash, readline

If I press `C-d` at the end of the input, the input is seemed to be flushed, but no `EOF` is sent to the program. If however I press `C-d` once more, `EOF` is sent.

Why is the EOF not sent the first time I press `C-d`? Where is this behavior documented?

To experiment youself play with `cat`, here is an example:

```
$ cat
abc<C-d>abc<C-d>
$
```

Comment: This is quite helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516122/how-to-capture-controld-signal/1516177#1516177

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-d` is the [End-of-transmission (EOT) character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character):

> In Unix the end-of-file character (by default EOT) causes the terminal
>   driver to make available all characters in its input buffer
>   immediately; normally the driver would collect characters until it
>   sees an end-of-line character. If the input buffer is empty (because
>   no characters have been typed since the last end-of-line or
>   end-of-file), a program reading from the terminal reads a count of
>   zero bytes. In Unix, such a condition is understood as having reached
>   the end of the file.

In your example, when you run `cat` and type a few characters followed by `C-d`, the characters typed to that point are sent to `cat` which prints them to the screen. Now the input buffer is empty, so when you type `C-d` again, `cat` reads zero bytes from the buffer and terminates because the end-of-file condition has been met.

Answer (score 0):

With bash you're probably using the readline library.

As you asked for the documentation, [here it is](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Bare-Essentials)

You'll see that Ctrl-D deletes the character underneath the cursor, and if you keep on reading, you'll discover lots of wonderful shortcuts!

Comment: It is wrong I think. After issuing a command I'm not in readline anymore. That is why I should also adjust the title.

Comment: @Beginner, of course you're using readline! after typing `abc` you have no character _underneath_ the cursor so Ctrl-D will not do anything. But if you go back one or two characters with the left arrow key, try Ctrl-D, it will indeed erase the character _underneath_ the cursor. Please also read [section 8.4.3](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Text) from the manual for the special case of a Ctrl-D issued at the beginning of an empty line.

Comment: Maybe we undestand each other, so here the key sequence I type in: ``cat<Enter>abc<left-arrow>``. What I see is afterwards actually this: ``cat<NEWLINE>abc^[[D``. So it does not allow me to go left. Those are the default settings on Arch and Debian.