# Exit a loop when stdin is EOF in C?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can I break out of this loop?

```
while(1){
    //continuously blink an led
    //stop when user hits CTRL+D
}
//do other stuff
```

I tried `while(fgets(s, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL)`, but of course it will wait for user input before continuing. I want the code inside the loop to run continuously, and break only the user hits `CTRL+D`.

I've done this at a low level with interrupts, but no clue how to do it in a high level environment.

Platform is Raspbian (Kernel 3.10) on Raspberry Pi

Comment: Will a Windows-specific answer satisfy your needs?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin a Linux answer would be ideal, preferably for Raspbian - I've updated my question.

Comment: Well, the literal answer to "How can I break out of this loop?" is `break;`... Sounds like your question should be more like "How do I detect EOF on `stdin`?"...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution transforming `Ctrl+D` into `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+C` into `Ctrl+D` using term caps may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516414/1405208.

`Ctrl+D` will therefore send the `SIGINT` signal. You just have to catch it. You may have to use a global variable though.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t ctrld_pressed = 0;

void ctrld(int sig)
{
  ctrld_pressed = 1;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, ctrld);
    while (!ctrld_pressed)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `ctrld_pressed` should be of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @black Edited my answer, though it is not mandatory (I wanted to keep my answer simple), it's always better to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As @unwind stated, you may use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int run = 1, rc;
   fd_set fd_list, readfd;

   FD_ZERO(&fd_list);
   FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fd_list);

   while (run)
  {
    readfd = fd_list;
    rc = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (rc == -1)
    {
        perror("Select error");
      return 1;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfd) && read(STDIN_FILENO, &rc, sizeof(rc)) == 0 )
      run = 0;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

We have told select to monitor for reading just one fd(STDIN_FILENO): the standard input one.
Once the user enters something, `select` will alert us of that event; we investigate to know whether that input comes from STDIN_FILENO and if so, we [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) from it. If `read` returns 0, that means an end-of-file was met.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `select()` if your platform supports it, otherwise you must make the input stream non-blocking ("raw") which again is highly platform-dependent code.