# Ubuntu equivalent of Ctrl + Z

Tags: c

In windows I used to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in cmd to mark the end of input to a C program.
What is its equivalent key combination for Ubuntu terminal?
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> seems to terminate my program rather than to terminate the input.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the implementation of the program. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> writes `EOF` to `stdin`, so it's up to the programmer to decide what to do with that input.

Comment: @Henrick Sorry for my noob question, but how to see the man page and what is it?

Comment: I think the man page is irrelevant since the program in question is one he has written himself.  If this were not the case the question has no place on SO. @AbhirupMondal - perhaps you should post your code too?

Comment: @Clifford I didn't catch that - good point

Comment: @Abhirup Never mind - I didn't catch that you were talking about your own program.

Comment: Ctrl-D does not really “write EOF”, it flushes. (To handle ctrl-D, the OP should handle OEF, though.) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/139746