# Why do i have to input EOF 3 times when using fgets?

Tags: c, while-loop, stdin, eof, fgets

So basically I want to copy everything i write to stdin (including newline char) to string for hash purposes. I managed to accomplish that and made small code to represent my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10000

int main()
{
char *myStr = calloc(1,1);
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

while( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) != NULL ){
  myStr = realloc(myStr, strlen(myStr)+1+strlen(buffer) );
  strcat( myStr, buffer );
}
printf("\n%s\n",myStr);

}
```

everything works when I enter some text then press ENTER and after I call EOF.

But when I start program enter "a" then I try to call EOF (using <kbd>Ctrl Z</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd> (Windows cmd prompt), <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> (Linux)) I have to do it three times for program to actually break the loop. I was expecting maximum of 2 times.

Can someone explain how using EOF, stdin and fgets works? Or should I use something else (for example getline)? I am sorry if I am not clear about my problem, just ask anything you need.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's an [explanation of how Ctrl+D works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/3386109).

Comment: You cannot use Ctrl+Z because the terminal uses Ctrl+Z to suspend the process!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Ctrl+Z is the EOF character on Windows.

Comment: Ok! I have forgotten Windows :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, ^Z or ^D are control characters that mean something to the terminal you are using, and *sometimes* that means for the terminal to signal end-of-file condition.

Anyway, your three keypresses are processed by the terminal to take the following actions, after entering text:

1. Flush the input (i.e. send the characters that have been input so far from the terminal to the program - by default this doesn't happen as the terminal uses line buffering)
2. Set end-of-file condition
3. Set end-of-file condition again

Inside your program that corresponds to:

1. Nothing happens: even though `a` is received, `fgets` keeps reading until end-of-file or newline
2. `fgets` completes because of end-of file. However it does not return NULL because characters were read, `"a"` to be specific.
3. [A bug in old versions of glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190) causes `fgets` to try to read again, even though it previously reached end-of-file. `fgets` completes because of end-of-file, and returns `NULL` because there were no characters read.

Comment: Note that the “lost” EOF can be detected by the short return with no newline or via `feof`.