# Why do I have to press CTRL-D three times to quit a program during an input?

Tags: python

Here's a simple Python program:

```
s = input('Name: ')
```

I ran the program, typed a few letters, and then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>:

```
$ python3 myscript.py
Name: myverylongna
```

Nothing happens, so I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> again. Nothing happens. Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for the third time. Python finally exits. I observe the same behavior using Python 2.7.

I don't understand why I had to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> three times to quit Python. For comparison, I wrote a C program to ask for user input (warning: the code has many mistakes):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Asks the user for string input.
 * Returns a pointer to the string entered by the user.
 * The pointer must be freed.
 */
char* input()
{
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char ch;
    size_t s_len = 0;
    while((ch = (char) getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        s[s_len] = ch;
        s_len++;
        s = realloc(s, (s_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (s == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: realloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    s[s_len] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Name: ");
    char *s = input();
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The C program only requires two presses of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for a similar input. Why?

Why does python need three presses of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to quit the program when the user is in the middle of entering characters at an input prompt?

(I am running Python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: I can't reproduce this; It takes me one `Ctrl-d` to exit the input, and possibly a second `Ctrl-d` to exit the interpreter (if I am running one).  What shell are you using?  (I'm running zsh 5.0.2 on Centos 7)

Comment: I don't see how the comparison with C is relevant, why would you expect the number of times you have to press Ctrl-d to be the same with 2 different code snippets in different languages?

Comment: Note that help(input) mentions: "If the user hits EOF (*nix: Ctrl-D, Windows: Ctrl-Z+Return), raise EOFError. On *nix systems, readline is used if available.". So your C code is far from equivalent to your python line, esp. if readline is used by ubuntu.

Comment: if this is a practical issue for you, use Ctrl-c once

Comment: It's not relevant to the behavior you're seeing, but there are many things wrong with your C version.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm running zsh 5.4.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm new to C, so it would really help if you could drop a few comments about the code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/228979

Comment: Related question for `fgets()` in C: [Why do i have to input EOF 3 times when using fgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759979/why-do-i-have-to-input-eof-3-times-when-using-fgets)

Comment: Per Wojciech Morawiec: possible duplicate of [Why do i have to input EOF 3 times when using fgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759979/why-do-i-have-to-input-eof-3-times-when-using-fgets)

Comment: Note that this is arguably a bug in Python: `input` should return after the second ^D since that does count as an EOF (rather than just a short read).