# Unable to read the last value in the code

Tags: c, algorithm, printf, getchar

I was meant to write a program so that it prints the number of stars. Example

Enter numbers : 12 11 9 8
^D

12 | ************ 
11 | *********** 
9  | ********* 
8  | ********

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int a;
printf("enter values \n");

while (scanf("%d ", &a) != EOF) {

    printf("%d |", a);

    for (int j = 1; j<= a; j++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

With my code it prints out the right output but it doesn't print out the number of stars for the last value I enter. Like in the above example it wont print out 8 stars until I hit the enter again or press ^D. I was wondering is there somethign wrong with my code. ?

Comment: In the above example, when does it print the line for each number relative to what you have typed in?

Comment: You should take a look at this first...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516122/how-to-capture-controld-signal

Comment: Try `scanf("%d", &a)` instead of `scanf("%d ", &a)`

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing wrong with your code.

`stdin` is line-buffered, so input can't be read until you press  or  (=ctrl-d in Linux).

There are libraries such as `conio.h` that provide non-buffered input.

Comment: But shouldn't it print them when I press enter. ?? It doesn't print the last one till I press cntrl+D

Comment: `stdout` is normally line buffered when connected to a terminal, so the `printf("\n");`should flush the output to the screen. You can try adding `fflush(stdout);` to programmatically flush the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space after `%d` inside `scanf("%d ", &a))`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    printf("enter values \n");

    while (scanf("%d", &a) != EOF) {

        printf("%d |", a);

        for (int j = 1; j<= a; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```