# Why does EOF behave differently in fgets and read

Tags: c, linux, fgets, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char           *s;
    char            buf[MAXLINE];

    s = fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin);    // here, if replaced with read(0, buf, MAXLINE);        

    return 0;
}
```

**Input is**：12`ctrl+d`

1. `fgets` doesn't return until input ctrl+d again(That is: 12`ctrl+dctrl+d`). Why doesn't fgets return when it encounts the first `EOF`? 
   It seems 12`ctrl+d` doesn't work.
2. But when `s = fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin);` is replaced with `read(0, buf, MAXLINE);` `read` will return(input is also: 12`ctrl+d`).

Comment: Because they are different functions? Why do you expect them to behave identical?

Comment: I think fgets should return when encounting EOF according to manual, but inputing 12`ctrl+d` fgets doesn't return.  fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an `EOF`  or  a  newline.

Comment: The standard does not specify when it does detect eof. Try redirecting `stdin` from a file in your shell and you will see different behaviour. Itr is a matter of the console buffering.

Comment: According to manual, fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  **Reading stops after an EOF  or  a  newine.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on the terminal:
>
> - simply means flush all the characters in `stdin` (the input buffer) immediately
> - it does NOT trigger an EOF condition on `stdin`
>   *(unless the current line/buffer is co-incidentally empty.)*

**So hitting CTRL+D while running a program**,

- **a blocked `fgetc()` will return if you do it twice consecutively.**
  *1st = flush currently buffered characters,

  2nd = flush empty buffer; i.e. `EOF` condition is valid for `fgetc()` and it returns*.
- **a blocked `fgetc()` will return if you do it once on an empty-line.**
  *flushes an already empty `stdin` buffer, i.e. `EOF` condition is valid for `fgetc()` and it returns.*
- **a blocked`read()` returns immediately as soon as the input is flushed.**

---

Checkout the answers to this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516122/319204)** for more details.

Comment: This answer is similarly wrong as the linked-to answer: there is no EOF-character. Also: which "buffer" do you mean: the buffer used by the (pseudo-) terminal driver, or stdio's buffer?

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser. I have updated the answer to avoid ambiguity and the incorrect terminology. I hope its very clear now.

Answer (score 3):

In common implementations `fgets` is based on a loop around `read`. If you call `fgets` it calls `read` internally. Typing <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> makes `read` return the two characters "12" to `fgets`. That does not yet make a full line, so `fgets` calls `read` again. Since we're reading from a terminal device, and not a file for example, `read` waits for you to type more data. If you type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> again, `read` returns 0 characters, which `fgets` interprets as an end of file and returns.