# Catch Ctrl+D after having read some input

Tags: c, input, user-input, eof, input-buffer

I'm trying to write a program that works like a UNIX terminal. So when Ctrl+D is pressed, it should exit. I'm reading input using:

```
char input[BUFFER_SIZE];
read(0, input, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

I'm also storing the output like this:

```
int num_read = read(0, input, BUFFER_SIZE);
//`read` is called only once. like this ^^^
```

Now I'm doing this to check `CTRL+D`:

```
if (num_read == 0)
{
    exit(CTRL_D_EXIT);
}
```

Now the question is how can I catch, `CTRL+D`, after some input? Like I've types `asdasdas` and then `CTRL+D`. Then I want to sound some alarm, or print a new line. How can I do so?

In my case, it just goes on executing the rest of the block as usual (size is not 0).

And here is a reference to Ctrl+D having a 0 size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516152/10305444

Comment: Ctrl+D registers as `EOF` when it's the first keystroke after an ENTER. Otherwise you need 2 Ctrl+Ds (note that Ctrl-D in the middle of the buffer is hard to catch).

Comment: Unrelated: if you're treating `input` as a string (`strlen()`, `printf()`, ...) you need to add the terminating `'\0'` manually: `read()` does not add it.